# How can I parse the Special:UnusedFiles of MediaWiki?

Tags: bash, mediawiki

My MediaWiki site has thousands of orphaned files listed in the Special:UnusedFiles page. There is no function to mass delete them. Going through these one at a time will take forever so the thought is to get the list of files dumped into a text file then run a cronjob to call the deleteBatch.php file.

I can run a wget on the page, like this and get a good list of files but at the end of the list there are items that do not belong:

```
    wget -q -O - http://www.example.com/wiki/Special:UnusedFiles | replace 
'/' '
' '\"' '
' | grep 'File' - | sort -u -
```

The end of the list has this, obviously I want only the File:file_name.jpg, and I need to spit it into a text file.

```
File:SV Splash late.jpg
File:SV_Splash_late.jpg
File:Untitled-2.png
File:VikingPromo.jpg
index.php?title=Special:UnusedFiles&amp;limit=100&amp;offset=0
index.php?title=Special:UnusedFiles&amp;limit=20&amp;offset=0
index.php?title=Special:UnusedFiles&amp;limit=250&amp;offset=0
index.php?title=Special:UnusedFiles&amp;limit=500&amp;offset=0
index.php?title=Special:UnusedFiles&amp;limit=50&amp;offset=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grep further to limit the results of the command and redirect the result in a file:

```
wget -q -O - http://www.example.com/wiki/Special:UnusedFiles | replace 
'/' '
' '\"' '
' | grep 'File' - | sort -u - | grep ^File > files_to_delete.txt
```

The `^` in the grep command means that the following `File` should be at the beginning of the line, the `>` redirects the output of the command to a file.